# tailwind.config.js purge option doesn't recognise PHP files and causes infinite recompiling

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I'm building out a custom WordPress theme with Tailwind and compiling assets with Laravel Mix 6.

In my `tailwind.config.js` file I have the following `purge` configuration:

```
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      './assets/**/*.{.js|.scss}',
      // './*.php',
      // './*/*.php',
      // './*/*/*.php',
    ],
    safelist: [
      // list any Tailwind classes which should never be purged, for example classes added via WordPress which are stored in the database
      // 'classname',
    ],
  },
```

Now, my first line works absolutely perfectly. It looks for any `.scss` or `.js` files inside my `assets` folder or subfolders and compiles on change. However if I uncomment any of the `.php` lines Laravel Mix constantly recompiles in the terminal even when I'm not making changes - it's completely endless.

[image]

I've narrowed the issue down to these lines, if they're not added it works fine, but I need them added so TailWind knows what classes are being used.

My `webpack.mix.js` for reference also:

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.js("assets/js/main.js", "build/scripts.js")
    .sass("assets/scss/main.scss", "build")
    .sourceMaps()
    .browserSync("wordpressthemedev.local")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [
            require("postcss-import"),
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("postcss-nested"),
            require("autoprefixer"),
        ],
    });
```

Additionally, if I do this:

```
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      './assets/**/*.{.js|.scss}',
      './parts/**/*.php',
      './functions/**/*.php',
      './404.php',
      './footer.php',
      './functions.php',
      './header.php',
      './index.php',
      './page.php',
      './search.php',
      './single.php',
      // './*/*/*.php',
    ],
    safelist: [
      // list any Tailwind classes which should never be purged, for example classes added via WordPress which are stored in the database
      // 'classname',
    ],
  },
```

Mix doesn't compile forever and does run fine, but I would rather avoid having to declare every PHP file at root level if possible

Comment: Any luck on this. I am also facing same issue while building Wordpress theme

Comment: Hey @AmarUbhe - I've not found a solution to this yet but I am actively working around it. Let me know if you find any information please :)

Comment: The major problem is composer vendor folder and node_modules, becase you told it look for every .php file it will have to traverse each available folder and node_modules + vendor can become very large, if you can find a way to ignore those folders it will cut the compile time

Comment: @Buttered_Toast thank you, compiled time isn't an issue though, its the fact it _constantly_ regenerates the assets when using `watch`

Comment: thats what watch is for, if you want to compile once you can use `dev` or `prod`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast No I think you misunderstand the problem, its _constantly_ recompiling the assets. Like I get hundreds of notifications saying compilation is complete. Watch should only fire when files its watching are saved, not compile forever when its first initially run, which is what the above issue is

Comment: Yeah notifications are a pain, add `mix.disableNotifications();` to webpack.mix.js to prevent those notifications. From the mix.js file it should only run when updateding the `assets/js/main.js` and `assets/scss/main.scss`. Try removing all other methods one by one and try to see if they cause the problem.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast already tried, the issue seems to lie with any file that isn't JS or SCSS unless folders/files are explicitly set which is something I want to avoid. We need the notifications so I don't want to disable them, the watcher still constantly runs in the terminal too/will refresh the preview link every time so its something that needs a solid solution rather than hiding it unfortunately

Comment: The only workaround I found is 
1. All root-level PHP files need to be added manually to purge array.
2. Subdirectory files you can add it like './parts/**/*.php',

Comment: An actual solution is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71160737/tailwind-laravelmix-infinity-loop-on-watch (thanks @james-seddon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, annoyingly there doesn't seem to be an easy way around this. As Myself and Amar highlighted, you can get around this if you explicitly set the names of the files within the purge array - but this isn't the most optimal solution especially if your implementation has a lot of files to check.

I did some extra digging, and if you're trying to use this with WordPress, I could really recommend starting with either [Roots Sage](https://roots.io/sage/) or [MountainBreeze](https://github.com/lukeraymonddowning/MountainBreeze) on a [Roots Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/) installation.

I personally find Sage a little too bloated out with unnecessary functions for most of the sites I build, so I'm running with Bedrock & MountainBreeze - A really nice combo so far!